# Why my query is not returning accurate results with Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using following Query to fetch duplicate records from a table.It is working fine for above requirements.

```
select tc_vessel_name, 
count(tc_vessel_name)as Vessel_Name from t_vessel_m as v
group by tc_vessel_name
having Vessel_Name >1
```

but the real problem is when i am using below query to find duplicate results having same id entry in other table then it is returning null results. i am not able to understand the real reason behind this.Please help me on this.

```
SELECT  tc_vessel_id,tc_vessel_name, COUNT(tc_vessel_name) AS Vesse_Name
FROM    t_vessel_m
WHERE   tc_vessel_id IN (SELECT tc_vessel_id FROM t_vessel_x) AND 
t_vessel_m.tc_is_deleted='F'
GROUP BY tc_vessel_name
HAVING ( COUNT(tc_vessel_name) > 1 )
```

Comment: What does this yield? `SELECT tc_vessel_id FROM t_vessel_x`

Comment: Actually i have 2 tables having common fields tc_vessel_id. so i am trying to find that records which have similar name count more then 1 and that same id exists in another table by using IN operator

Comment: I created both tables and created duplicate (id and name) records. It came back with the a row showing the duplicate. Could it be something unexpected in your data?

Comment: there is nothing unexpected because we are using here id and when i tried to search with above query it is returning results and when i fount manually that id in another table it exists in that table but second query is not showing that records

Comment: In order to duplicate your problem, I suggest either creating an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) or posting your structure for these two tables with 2-3 relevant records that aren't working. Since my structure and records are working, either I misunderstand your structure or something about yours is throwing it off and needs to be duplicated. The query is fine as written.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly finding duplicates in first query. This:

```
select tc_vessel_name, 
count(tc_vessel_name)as Vessel_Name from t_vessel_m as v
group by tc_vessel_name
having Vessel_Name > 1
```

should be this:

```
select tc_vessel_name, 
count(tc_vessel_name)as Vessel_Name from t_vessel_m as v
group by tc_vessel_name
having count(Vessel_Name) > 1
```

What you really doing is comparing not count of groups but value of grouping to 1. So first and second statements are different. Look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5895/1  There are no dups but you get 2 rows as a result. In `Sql Server` it would give you a cast exception, but it implicitly converts 1 to varchar in `MySql`.

Comment: Then you are probably filtering duplicates out  with `t_vessel_m.tc_is_deleted='F'`

Comment: I also tried to remove those field but still there was a problem with that that is why i am triying to find the actual problem behind this

Comment: I have a large data and when i am nit using a IN or NOT IN with  my query it is returning 419 results but after using IN operator it is returning empty results but when i tried to search manually one record in another table it exists